# Confusion about constants in Java

Tags: java, constants

I'm in the middle of studying java programming and I'm a bit confused about constants. From what I've read so far constants are final and cannot be reassigned a new value unlike variables. However, when I'm using the Calender class there is the set method which seems to change a constant field. For example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("The year is " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2001);
System.out.println("The year is " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

If the `Calendar.YEAR` field is declared `final` in the `Calendar` class then why am I able to change it to another value using the set method?

Comment: This is how you "get" the constant: `Calendar.YEAR`. And this is how you "set" it: `Calendar.YEAR = 3`. Try it and see it fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `calendar.set(blah, blahVal)` is not updating the first params `(Calendar.YEAR)`, it update the value which is internally maintain by the calendar,
for example if you give `cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2001)` Calendar.YEAR is a constant which is index of an array. that array contain the specified value. that value is update dramatically.

Comment: Oh Ok that makes sense. Is this the protected int[] fields found in the Calendar class the array which you referring to?

Answer (score 5):

`Calendar.YEAR` is just a constant saying *which* logical field you want to set within the calendar.

The aim was to avoid having an API with

```
setYear
setDay
setMonth
...
```

In retrospect, I'd say this was a spectacularly bad idea - along with most of the rest of the design of `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date`.

So this call:

```
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2001)
```

doesn't change the value of `Calendar.YEAR`... it changes some other (private) field within the `Calendar` object.

Comment: Arguably, having `set` of any kind was a spectacularly bad idea :)

Comment: @Unihedron It is a bad idea because Java was left without a *date* value class, which is today widely regarded as the only sane approach. The design of `Calendar` stems from the heyday of applets and has Swing's fingerprints all over: the only use case it works well with is a GUI date control. There, mutability makes sense, as well as int-keyed fields, as well as allowing arbitrary changes to any field, then recalculating to a "normalized" form. The lack of useful constructors is another example which is fine for GUI, but stupid for everything else.

Comment: @tomasb: As Marko said, making it mutable was a bad idea to start with. But the whole "fields and one method instead of many methods" has caused *so* many problems over time. Basically the java.util.* time API is a disaster area.

Comment: Additionally we could argue that, since Calendar.YEAR is an int, we could only change its value if Java would support Call-by-reference

Comment: And that's just scratching the surface. Date and time is a mad enough area without extra technical quirks thrown in.

Answer (score 3):

`Calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, xx)` changes the value of the year (for the calendar instance), not the value of `Calendar.YEAR` ([which is `1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.YEAR)), see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

NB: it's easy to make a [short program](http://ideone.com/UT3A0w) to verify that.

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar.YEAR` is just an `int` which is defined in [Constant Field Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.YEAR), see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR):

```
public static final int YEAR
```

It's not changing constant field, this `int` defines what field should be changed, see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.set%28int%2Cint%29):

```
1196    public void set(int field, int value)
1197    {
1198        if (isLenient() && areFieldsSet && !areAllFieldsSet) {
1199            computeFields();
1200        }
1201        internalSet(field, value);
1202        isTimeSet = false;
1203        areFieldsSet = false;
1204        isSet[field] = true;
1205        stamp[field] = nextStamp++;
1206        if (nextStamp == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
1207            adjustStamp();
1208        }
1209    }
```

Take a look at the [docs `Calendar#set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-) to better understand what it does.